# Cleanup output from GDB memory dump

Tags: linux, bash, debugging, gdb, memory-dump

We lost a configuration file which we were able to recover some of the data with a gdb memory dump but many important parts of the file are buried in memory noise.

Is there a way to cleanup the dump files?

Example output

[image]

Comment: The `strings` command might help in extracting readable info.

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: @jordanm - Thanks! That removed the garbage and helped recover some of the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `strings` command was able to remove the garbage from the file.

```
strings mem_7fbf71165000 > strings.txt
```